# Pop-up script alert in .bat

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to create a pop-up alert to remember something every time I switch on my laptop.

Someone told me that I can use a bat/batch script.

I have tried this:

```
@echo off
echo x=msgbox("Blahblahblah" ,0, "Alert") >> msgbox.vbs

start msgbox.vbs
```

And it works only when I click on the file saved on my desktop. But I don't know what to do to make it run automatically when I switch on my laptop. I mean, I want to see the pop-up message every time I switch it on.

Comment: If you're eager to learn more, there are various available resources for that. You should do a research and try to implement it on your own first. Then if you are still facing a specific roadblocks, add your research and attempts as well as a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Simply put a link to your file into your startup directory (Start>Programs>startup)

Comment: By "every time I switch on my laptop" can be taken to mean that you only want the script to run when you startup from a full shutdown, but it could also be taken to mean that you want the script to run when returning the laptop from sleep or hibernate. What you specifically want to have happen will determine if the correct solution is something like placing the script in Start\Programs\startup or perhaps creating a task to run on wake up as described here: https://sumtips.com/how-to/run-program-windows-wakes-up-sleep-hibernate. Please clarify.

Comment: Further details on how you want the reminder to work would also be useful. As described, it sounds like you just want to display the same static message every time you "switch on your laptop", which sort of sounds like the electronic equivalent of tying a string around your finger. Do you have a source for a changing reminder message perhaps? Have you considered using a reminder program such Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Possible answers to your question are:

1. Create a shortcut to your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) within your Startup directory, `C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.
2. Run the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) from the registry, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.
3. Use the Task Scheduler, `"%__AppDir__%taskschd.msc" /s`.

As this site is for code, not providing links for your research, I will allow you to look into each of the above yourself.

Additionally, you could also use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), *as opposed to [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem Message to display.
Set "message=Blahblahblah"
Rem Window title to display.
Set "caption=Reminder"
Rem Displayed icon. Use either Enumerator or ValueType.
Rem  0  None                  No symbols.
Rem 16  Error|Hand|Stop       White X in a circle with a red background.
Rem 32  Question              Question mark in a circle. Do not use, included only for backward compatibility.
Rem 48  Exclamation|Warning   Exclamation point in a triangle with a yellow background.
Rem 64  Asterisk|Information  Lowercase letter i in a circle.
Set "icon=Information"
Rem Displayed button. Use either Enumerator or ValueType.
Rem 0  OK           OK button. 
Rem 1  OKCancel     OK and Cancel buttons.
Rem 3  YesNoCancel  Yes, No, and Cancel buttons.
Rem 4  YesNo        Yes and No buttons.
Set "button=0"

PowerShell -NoProfile^
 "[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')|Out-Null;"^
 "[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('%message%','%caption%','%button%','%icon%')"
```

Comment: If my answer is the best solution you have received, please consider marking it as accepted, _by clicking on the large grayed out check mark to its left_, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this. I know it's dirty but works fine.
Put these lines your bat or CMD file

```
@echo x=msgbox("Hello world!" ,0, ".:: Hello world! ::.") >%temp%\alert.vbs

wscript %temp%\alert.vbs
```